# Could you write the sentence in bold in other words?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Now he starts to stir. The fluttering of his eyelids is a response to some age-old, unexplainable instinct that the sun is nearly down and his time is near. Tonight, he is particularly hungry and as he lies there, fully awake now, in red-lined Inverness cape and tails, waiting to feel with uncanny perception the precise moment of darkness before opening the lid and emerging, he decides who this evening's victims will be. The baker and his wife, he thinks to himself.
>
> Succulent, available, and unsuspecting. The thought of **the unwary couple whose trust he has carefully cultivated excites his blood lust to a fever pitch**, and he can barely hold back these last seconds before climbing out of the coffin to seek his prey.

I don't get the meaning of the sentence in bold clearly.

I don't know "whose" refer to whom? and "trust" is noun or verb?

Answer (score 1):

In short, "whose" is the couple, and "trust" is a noun.

In detail:

## Rephrase the sentence.

### Add commas (for clarity):

> The thought of **the unwary couple, whose trust he has carefully cultivated, excites his blood-lust to a fever pitch,** and he can barely hold back, these last seconds, before climbing out of the coffin, to seek his prey.

Remember that "whom" and "whose" cause sentences to be inverted from their usual word order.  So if we flip the sentence, back to its normal word order, it will make more sense.  To do that, we need to separate this very long sentence into multiple parts.

### Let's reorder and separate:

> **He had** carefully **cultivated** the unwary couple's **trust**.
>
> **The thought** {of the unwary couple} **excites his blood-lust** {to a fever pitch}.
>
> {Before climbing out of the coffin to seek his prey}, [*during*] **these last [few] seconds** he can barely hold back, [*because he is so excited*].

To see how the sentence works, you can often remove prepositional phrases without affecting the grammar.   You can also remove adverbs and adjectives to see the structure more clearly.  (All of these are very important for meaning!)

### Now as simple as possible:

> He had cultivated trust.
>
> The thought excites him.
>
> He can barely hold back.

The sentence feels very different now, but this is the basic structure it is using.

Comment: Lots of thanks. I thought "cultivated" is an adjective and because of that I couldn't get the meaning. you relieved me.

Comment: I don't know why this question got negative point. I am learning English and this sentence puzzled me.

Comment: I think the question is a good one — perhaps you could have included “what you think it means or what research you have done,” as some people ask for — but I don’t think it was necessary.    I also don’t think people should leave “down votes” without any explanation.  That is “bad form”.